# jQuery - OnClick, change background color for table cells always when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example: 
You have a table, and it has 4 tds and 2 trs. Table's background color is white. If i click to A td, A td should be red, than if i click to B, B td should be red and A td should be red too. If i click to C than, C should be red and B and A should be red too.

I have something like this. But it isnt good, because when i click again i want to change color back to white.

http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/193/

The code i use

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="function()">AAA</td>
        <td onclick="function()">BBB</td>
        <td onclick="function()">CCC</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td onclick="function()">DDD</td>
        <td onclick="function()">EEE</td>
        <td onclick="function()">FFF</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$( function() {
  $('td').click( function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#aaa')
  } );
} );
```

Comment: you want [This](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/k8UgT/194/)  or [This](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/k8UgT/196/)

Comment: If you are using jQuery you don't need to define onclick function on <td>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

First of all you don't need to `onclick` attribute on the td's. Second of all I would suggest using a CSS class instead of setting the background color.

**CSS**

```
.red-cell {
   background: #F00; /* Or some other color */
}
```

**JS**

```
$( function() {
  $('td').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("red-cell");
  } );
} );
```

Read more about toggleClass [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/200/)

Comment: Is there anyway to tell if the page has already added a "red-cell", if so can it be removed before you add "red-cell" to the next cell you click on? Kind of like so only one cell can be red at a time?

Comment: @KerynGill I am not sure that I am following. Do you mean that you want to allow only one red cell at the time?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. I believe I got it using this...
    <script>
    $( function() {
    $('.productslider div.slide a.addclassonbtn').on('click',function(){
    $('.productslider div.slide a.addclassonbtn').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    });
    </script>

Answer (score 4):

Use a CSS class for the red background and then use `.toggleClass()` in your JavaScript.

JavaScript

```
$('td').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

CSS

```
td.on {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/198/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$( function() {
  $('td').click( function() {
      if($(this).attr('style'))
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
      else
    $(this).css('background', '#aaa')
  } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( function() {
  $('td').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
  },function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
  });
} );
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/199/