# Changing cell Backcolor on DataGridView CellMouseClick

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors, mouseclick-event

I want to invert cell back color by clicking on cell and using below code

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor =
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor == Color.Black
                ? Color.White
                : Color.Black;
    }
```

but this code works on cell leave. I want to paint cell instantly on click. Which event should I use?

Comment: Why not use jquery to do it? (Then there is no postback to server just to change cell color) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618169/jquery-onclick-change-background-color-for-table-cells-always-when-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken. The code works immediately. You just can't see it as the click is also **selecting** the Cell and the selection color is taking precedence.

To make it show right away simply add this to the event:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = false;
```

Comment: Worked! thank you very much. Before I have done like that : dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor; on form load, but you are right.