# jQuery - coloring cells on mouse click or hold

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a task to recreate paint kind of by making 100 x 50 cells and onlcick giving them a background color that is selected. But to make the drawing easier a user should be able to hold his mouse button and drag over the cells to make them fill in with a background color. As soon as he releases the mouse button the drawing should stop and you are back to clicking or have to hold the mouse button again.

I have tried to do this with a .mousemove but that did not work out.

```
// MAKING THE GRID
for (let i = 1; i <= 49; i++){
    $('#canvas').append('<tr id="table' + i + '"</tr>');
    for(let j = 1; j <= 100; j++){
        $('#table' + i).append('<td></td>');
    }
}

// ADDING A COLOR ON CLICK
$('td').click(function kleur(){
    if($(this).attr('style')){
        $(this).removeAttr('style')
    } else {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + color);
    }
})

// SELECTING COLOR ON RIGHT CLICK
$('td').mousedown(function(e) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
        $('.popup').show();
        $('.popup').css({left: e.pageX});
        $('.popup').css({top: e.pageY});
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618212/3061689

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - OnClick, change background color for table cells always when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618169/jquery-onclick-change-background-color-for-table-cells-always-when-clicked)

Comment: Can you clarify in what way it "did not work out"?  The more clearly you can describe your problem, the easier it will be for us to help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try listen to mouseover event and check if the button was pressed. It would look somehow like:

```
$("#canvas").on("mouseover", function(e) {
if(e.buttons == 1)
 Draw(e.target);
});
```

I made quick example for you (in vanilla JS unfortunately, I dont use jQuery anymore):
https://codepen.io/DooMxDD/pen/RmWqjM

Answer (score 0):

It worked out by adding these lines of code.

```
// Adding the selected color to coloring function
function kleur(target) {
    target.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
// Coloring when mouse is held down
$("#canvas").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    if(e.buttons == 1)
     kleur(e.target);
});
```